# Bluetooth for RTL8723DE is not working...!

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, hp, realtek-wireless

Recently, I have purchased a new NoteBook of HP-BS145TU Series.

They only provide support for Windows.

I have two questions:

1. Is it fine to run Ubuntu on this machine?
2. With some workaround, I could figure out, the way for Wi-Fi working, but couldn't proceed for the BlueTooth Functioning.

Please guide me properly.

Comment: I think question 1 will attract only primarily opinion based answers. As you've mentioned Wi-Fi and Bluetooth don't work (out of box). This might be a massive deal-breaker for many, whereas others may be okay with it.

Answer (score 0):

I own an HP-15-BS576TX laptop bought on October 2017 in India, which has the same specifications as yours minus the processor which is Intel 7200U Core i5 (7th gen). For me, except Bluetooth, everything is working fine with Ubuntu 17.10. Keyboard shortcuts (volume control etc).

1. Yes, it runs fine on Ubuntu. Prior to installation of Linux operating system, Enable UEFI, Disable Secure Boot, Disable Legacy support.
2. I have explained how I installed the WiFi driver in this page: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/m-p/6477307/highlight/true#M146067

For Bluetooth also, firmware is available, but no one to guide. rtlwifi-new maintainer has said that he cannot help with bluetooth. But, it will also get supported probably soon. The error message is some "hci0: didn't find patch for chip id 2".